# HP Chromebook G1 device locked by google.com

Tags: chromebook

I got this warning on my Chromebook. How to solve it?

[image: device got locked]

Comment: Any more information? Did you buy this on second hand?

Comment: @davidbaumann yes. They just said this device was locked. They was unable to fix it, so they sell it at lower price. I put my bet on this. Search all over internet how to solve it.

Comment: Probably stolen.

Comment: this "warning" means that device was locked by admin of the domain it belongs to.

Comment: So that information you add after asking?

Answer (score 1):

You very likely bought stolen property belonging to Google. That it's a Chromebook (meaning Google is also a manufacturer) is a coincidence. You should report the seller to the police, and ask them what to do with the stolen laptop.